# convergence for dependent random variables

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be a sample of iid rvs. Suppose their distribution has a parameter $0<\theta<\infty$ and support $(0,\infty)$. Let $\theta_n=\theta_n(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ be an estimator of $\theta$ such that $\theta_n>0$ and $\theta_n\to\theta$ a.s. as $n\to\infty$.

Consider  $Y_n=\max_{1\le j\le n} X_j^{\theta-\theta_n}$. Since $\theta_n\to\theta$ a.s. as $n\to\infty$, is it reasonable to expect that $Y_n\approx O_p(1)$ at least when $n$ is sufficiently large? Can this actually be shown more rigorously? Note that $X_j^{\theta-\theta_n}$ for $1\le j\le n$ are dependent.

Comment: Actually it is more reasonable to expect that $Y_n\to\infty$, at least when the tail of the distribution of the $X_k$s is large enough.

Comment: I see. What about $Z_n=\min_{1\le j\le n} X_j^{\theta-\theta_n}$?